# iPhone 4 Stopped Charging

Tags: iphone, ios, charge

My iPhone 4 has stopped being able to be charged.  I have tried two different cords and have tried plugging it into my computer, but nothing works.  There is not an Apple Store close.  What are some things that I should try?

Comment: How are you determining that charging has stopped? Have you gone through the troubleshooting steps at support.apple.com after making sure the phone is backed up (assuming there is any power left)?

Comment: How I am determining that charging has stopped - I have tried to charge it multiple times and with multiple cords and nothing happens.  There is no power left.  The only thing that I can get to happen at this point is that if I hold down the power button, I get the screen that indicates that I need to charge it.

Answer (score 2):

From [iPhone and iPod touch: Charging the battery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1476?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US):

> If your battery doesn't charge, or if your device shows a low-battery image, black screen, or "accessory not supported" alert, follow these steps.
>
> - Inspect the connector at the bottom of the phone:
>
>   - Make sure that there are no bent pins in the connector.
>   - Make sure that the connector is free from debris.
>   - If there are bent pins or debris, please contact Apple Support.
> - Otherwise, continue troubleshooting.
> - Make sure that the outlet you're using works.
> - Make sure that the Apple USB cable and Apple USB power adapter work.
> - Plug the device in to power and let it charge until your device turns on. This could take between 10 and 30 minutes. If you don't have an Apple USB power adapter, try connecting to a computer's high-power USB 2.0 port (not a keyboard). The computer must be on.
> - If the device still exhibits an issue, try turning your device off and then on again while connected to power.
> - If the issue persists, please contact [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/contact/).

Comment: Thanks.  Tried those things short of Apple Support.  Nothing works.

Comment: @bill999 sadly sounds like it needs a repair. Thanks for clarifying things in your comments. In the future, consider listing precisely what you did to avoid getting a general answer if you need specific advice (and vice versa)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of how to phrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found from personal experience (not only my cell-phone) that debris are very often the root cause of the "not supported cable" alert.

Cleaning the female connector (on the device) always fixed the problem in these cases.

Comment: I got the lint out.  I haven't scraped the pins off or anything.  How should I do that?

Comment: am not sure what you mean. Have you cleaned the device end of the connector? if you did the that would be it.

Comment: Yes.  I'll probably have to get a new one.